# Executing Another Assembly Program in Assembly (MIPS)

Tags: linux, assembly, process, fork, mips

for my homework I need to know how to call an assembly program inside an assembly program in Linux MIPS.

For example, I have an assembly program that executes different assembly files like for greeting user, for getting inputs from user, for calculating needed calculations etc.

I want to call all the necessary programs in my main assembly program when the time comes and wait for them to be finished. This is kinda like fork function in C. I know I can write functions instead of this but homework includes executing another assembly program in assembly. Could anyone help me? All I need is how to call another program inside a program. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You haven't specified the environment in which you are running your programs.

Comment: Are you using Linux MIPS?  If so then yes, make `fork`+`exec` system calls and collect the output somehow (maybe via `pipe`).  That seems super clunky for such small tasks, though.
 If you're using SPIM or MARS simulators, https://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/Help/SyscallHelp.html doesn't list a fork / exec or CreateProcess equivalent that I can see.  You could potentially load machine code from a file and jump to it.

Comment: Or do you actually just want to write *functions* / subroutines within one program and call them with `jal` / return with `jr $ra`?  For the scope of task you're talking about (like printing a greeting vs. getting input), separate functions not separate programs sounds like what you want.

Comment: 1) Yes, I'm using Linux MIPS.
2) That was just a simple example. As I said I need to call another assembly file to execute.
3) Thanks for your answer. But I couldn't find the syscall to make fork+exec. Could you please open that up a little bit more? Thanks.

Comment: https://www.linux-mips.org/wiki/Syscall

Comment: hello Crystal, you might update your question to reflect the fact you are working on Linux MIPS

Comment: You need syscall support for this. By default, `mars` doesn't have such a syscall. But, if needed to, you could download the `mars` source and rebuild it. It has a special directory for syscalls. You can add a source file (`.java`) that you write that has the proper support, add it to the directory, rebuild, and get the syscall loader to load it. Yes, a _lot_ of work ...

Comment: *This is kinda like fork function in C* The C `fork(2)` function is just a wrapper around the Linux `fork` system call, which you can and should invoke directly with the `syscall` instruction. (Then execve).  See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html for a table of syscall ABIs, including MIPS.  The POSIX system-call API is the same whether you're calling it from C or asm on Linux.  (Although a couple Linux system calls differ slightly from the POSIX function, notably brk/sbrk; the Notes section of Linux man pages mentions any differences.  Most have none.)